# jquery: changing css and removing html not working

Tags: jquery, css

This HTML:

```html
<div class="editable" contentEditable="true">
    <span class="empty">change me</span>
</div>
```

and this JQuery:

```js
$(".empty").click(function() {
            $(this).css("color","#000");
            $(this).html(" ");
        });
```

aren't working as I hoped (or at all).  I want to make it so when a user clicks on the "change me" text in the span that the font color changes to black and the existing text in the span goes away.

Comment: its working... http://jsfiddle.net/JftGd/5/

Comment: by not working do you mean the text is not disappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not work because there is no height property for the span, and after emptying it's contents it will have a `width of 0px` and a `height of 0px`. Replace the span with a `<div>` and give it a height in your css. 
example here: http://jsfiddle.net/JftGd/12/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your code in the `<head>` of you html.
You need to wrap your code in onLoad, so the code will be executed at the proper time.

```
$(function() {
    $(".empty").click(function() {
        $(this).css("color","#000");
        $(this).html(" ");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code after the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(ev){
   $(".empty").click(function() {
        $(this).css("color","#000");
        $(this).html(" ");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sF6G9/